# JavaScript uninitialised variable behaviour

Tags: javascript

i am learning JavaScript. I encountered this behaviour using initialised and uninitialised variable.
For example,

```js
//Not initialised
var sum;
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    sum = sum + i;
}
alert(sum);
output:90
```

```js
//Initialised
var sum = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    sum = sum + i;
}
alert(sum);
output:45
```

Could someone explain me what is happening here? I think not initialised variable sum adds 45 two times it seems.

**Edit:**
Please try running the code separately.

Comment: `90`? You are supposed to get `NaN`.

Comment: I am getting NAN and 45 . [look here](http://jsfiddle.net/saikumarm4/vdcje3p8/)

Comment: It should come as NAN since the value is undefined and you are adding it with a number.

Comment: i am using scratchpad from mozilla to run the code. it outputs 90.

Comment: you will get NAN and 45//

Comment: Scratchpad remembers variables' values, so yes, your first snippet alerts 90 when you run it for the second, third etc time. Close the current tab and reopen the SP, and you will see `NaN`.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/qody0b61/ `alert(typeof(sum))` === undefinded so you can not add numbers to a variable which doesn't know what it is. it's like adding apples with bananas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First one would return NaN (not a number). I don't think it would alert 90. I didn't, I tried your script.
while in the second one you explicitly inform the script that you are using numbers

```
var sum = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   sum = sum + i;
}
```